# Obtain the boundary of the keyboard by open cv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a virtual keyboard in opencv and python. I need to detect the largest contour to obtain the boundary of the keyboard and the coordinates of the corners.

Here is what I actually need:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.1.100:8080/shot.jpg'

while (True):

  imgResp = requests.get(url)
  imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResp.content), dtype=np.uint8)
  frame = cv2.imdecode(imgNp, -1)

  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(hsv, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

  thresh1, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)


  cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh1)
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

  # Q Quit
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the contours themselves you need to find the **bounding box** around the largest contour.

Find the largest contour and draw the bounding box using `cv2.boundingRect()` :

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

where `cnt` is the largest contour in the image and the 4 corners of the rectangle are `x, y, x+w, y+h`

Check out the bounding rectangle section given in this [LINK](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cv2.RETR_LIST` parameter, use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`

```
thresh1, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Checkout [this](https://loctv.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/learn-opencv3-python-contours-convex-contours-bounding-rect-min-area-rect-min-enclosing-circle-approximate-bounding-polygon/) tutorial to get more information.